# The NPM script 'serve' exited without indicating that the server was listening for requests: 'npm' is not an internal or external command

Tags: vue.js

When I use VueCliMiddleware library to set up a vue project under IIS enviourment. there is an error. Hope someone can make some suggestions here. Thanks!:

```
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'serve' exited without indicating that the server was listening for requests. The error output was: 'npm' not an internal or external command, nor is it a executable program. ))

    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.get_Result()
    VueCliMiddleware.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout<T>(Task<T> task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, string message) in Internals.cs
                    return task.Result;
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task<Uri> baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, bool proxy404s)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass2_0+<<UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer>b__0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

The vue project can be hosted in http://localhost:8080 by using quasar dev command, but if I change it into IIS by a webapplication name, such as http://localhost/sfwd2/, the error will be thrown.

The npm version information is here:
[image]

The Startup.cs source code:

```
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(opt => opt.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", policy =>
                    {
                        policy
                        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080")   
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowCredentials();
                    });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthorization()
            .UseCors("AllowAll");


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "api/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
       {
           spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

           if (env.IsDevelopment())
           {
               spa.UseVueCli(npmScript: "serve", forceKill: true);
           }
       });
    }
}
```

The package.json under ClientApp folder:

```
  "name": "quasar-demo-2021",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A Quasar Framework app",
  "productName": "Slickflow.WebDemo",
  "author": "besley <william.ligong@hotmail.com>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "quasar dev",
    "build": "quasar build",
    "build:pwa": "quasar build -m pwa",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue ./",
    "test": "echo \"No test specified\" && exit 0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "quasar": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.0.0",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@quasar/app": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 10 Chrome versions",
    "last 10 Firefox versions",
    "last 4 Edge versions",
    "last 7 Safari versions",
    "last 8 Android versions",
    "last 8 ChromeAndroid versions",
    "last 8 FirefoxAndroid versions",
    "last 10 iOS versions",
    "last 5 Opera versions"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 10.18.1",
    "npm": ">= 6.13.4",
    "yarn": ">= 1.21.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tried many solutions serveral hours, we have found the reason which is caused npm global path.

We used the command: npm config ls:
[image]

The default npm path: C:\Program Files\nodejs is not a correct enviroument path variable, it still need to add the prefix variable into the global enviourment. In my case the correct path: C:\Users\lg\AppData\Roaming\npm

This will fix the issue of the error.